# EF Core creates a Shadow FK Index while OnModelCreating and Its causing run time error

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I am migrating from Entity Framework to Ef Core and ran into this issue where EF Core is creating a shadow FK Index property and adding 1 at the end as the same-named property already exists in my class.

```
>  TabCode (decimal) Required Index
>         Annotations: 
>           Relational:ColumnType: decimal(10, 0)
>       TabCode1 (no field, Nullable<decimal>) Shadow FK Index



>  Foreign keys: 
>           PaymentBatch {'ParentPaymentBatchId'} -> PaymentBatch {'PaymentBatchId'} ToDependent: PaymentBatch1 ToPrincipal:
> PaymentBatch2 ClientSetNull
>             Annotations: 
>               Relational:Name: FK_PaymentBatch_PaymentBatch
>           PaymentBatch {'TabCode1'} -> Tab {'TabCode'} ToPrincipal: Tab ClientSetNull
>         Indexes: 
>           ParentPaymentBatchId 
>           TabCode1
```

The above code is from `modelBuilder` `ToDebugString()` result object. **I keep getting error saying TabCode1 column doesn't exist.** when I try to run the page. `TabCode` is the property that has the same name as one of the index.
I checked the DB and we have a Non-Clustered index defined which I have defined in `OnModelCreating` as well. I am not sure what this **Shadow FK Index** is, and How do I define it in my `modelBuilder`.

Below is how I am defining my index in modelBuilder

```
entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.PaymentBatchId, e.TabCode, e.TentType, e.TaxYear }, "TRX_PaymentCodeTentTypeTaxYear")
                .IsUnique();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
entity.HasOne<Tab>(d => d.Tab)
                    .WithMany(p => p.PaymentBatch)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.TabCode);
```

The above code fixed my issue. Turns out EF core needs to define any relationship that doesn't exist in SQL and we were adding a navigational property in our EF.